# Stateful generators with Haskell pipes

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

1. Suppose I want to model, using Haskell pipes, a Python
   `Generator[int, None, None]` which keeps some internal state. Should
   I be using `Producer int (State s) ()` or `StateT s (Producer int m) ()`, where `m` is whatever type of effect I eventually want from
   the consumer?
2. How should I think about the notion of transducers in pipes? So in
   Oleg's [simple generators](https://okmij.org/ftp/continuations/PPYield/#gen-Haskell), there is

   ```
   type Transducer m1 m2 e1 e2  = Producer m1 e1 -> Producer m2 e2
   ```

   but I don't know what the analog is in pipes, because any `Proxy`
   objects that interact seem to rely on the same underlying monad `m`,
   not switching from `m1` to `m2`. See the [Prelude](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.16/docs/Pipes-Prelude.html) functions, for
   instance.

I think I'm just misunderstanding something fundamental about the way pipes works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `pipes`, you typically wouldn't use effects in the base monad `m` of your overall `Effect` to model the **internal** state of a `Producer`. If you really wanted to use `State` for this purpose, it would be an internal implementation detail of the `Producer` in question (discharged by a `runStateP` or `evalStateP` inside the `Producer`, as explained below), and the `State` would not appear in the `Producer`'s type.

It's also important to emphasize that a `Producer`, even when it's operating in the `Identity` base monad without any "effects" at its disposal, isn't some sort of pure function that would keep producing the same value over and over without monadic help.  A `Producer` is basically a stream, and it can maintain state using the usual functional mechanisms (e.g., recursion, for one).  So, you definitely don't *need* a `State` for a `Producer` to be stateful.

The upshot is that the usual model of a Python `Generator[int, None, None]` in `Pipes` is just a `Monad m => Producer Int m ()` polymorphic in an unspecified base monad `m`.  Only if the `Producer` needs some external effects (e.g., `IO` to access the filesystem) would you require more of `m` (e.g., a `MonadIO m` constraint or something).

To give you a concrete example, a `Producer` that generates pseudorandom numbers obviously has "state", but a typical implementation would be a "pure" `Producer`:

```
randoms :: (Monad m) => Word32 -> Producer Int m ()
randoms seed = do
  let seed' = 1664525 * seed + 1013904223
  yield $ fromIntegral seed'
  randoms seed'
```

with the state maintained via recursion.

If you *really* decided to maintain this state via the `State` monad, the type of the `Producer` wouldn't change.  You'd just use a `State` internally.  The `Pipes.Lift` module provides some helpers (like `evalStateP` used here) to locally add a monad layer to facilitate this:

```
randoms' :: (Monad m) => Word32 -> Producer Int m ()
randoms' seed = evalStateP seed $ forever $ do
  x <- get
  let x' = 1664525 * x + 1013904223
  yield $ fromIntegral x'
  put x'
```

Oleg's simple generators are entirely different.  His producers and consumers produce and consume values *only* through monadic effects, and "monad changing" is central to the implementation.  In particular, I believe his consumers and transducers can *only* maintain state via a monadic effect, like a `State` monad, though I'd have to look a little more carefully to be sure.

In contrast, `pipes` proxies can produce and consume values and maintain internal state independent of the underlying base monad.

Ultimately, the analog of Oleg's transducers in `pipes` are simply the `Pipe`s.  Both consume values from a producer and yield values to a consumer.  The monad changing in Oleg's transducers is just an implementation detail.